# Teradata sql query from grouping records using Intervals

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata SQL how to assign same row numbers for the group of records created with in 8 seconds of time Interval.

Example:-

```
Customerid Customername   Itembought   dateandtime
                                       (yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
100           ALex        Basketball   2017-02-10 10:10:01
100           ALex        Circketball  2017-02-10 10:10:06
100           ALex        Baseball     2017-02-10 10:10:08
100           ALex        volleyball   2017-02-10 10:11:01
100          ALex         footbball    2017-02-10 10:11:05
100          ALex         ringball     2017-02-10 10:11:08
100         Alex          football     2017-02-10 10:12:10
```

My Expected result  shoud have additional column with Row_number where it should assign the same number for all the purchases of the customer with in 8 seconds: Refer the below expected result

```
Customerid Customername Itembought dateandtime            Row_number
                                   (yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) 
100           ALex      Basketball 2017-02-10 10:10:01      1
100           ALex      Circketball 2017-02-10 10:10:06     1
100           ALex      Baseball    2017-02-10 10:10:08     1
100          ALex       volleyball  2017-02-10 10:11:01     2
100          ALex       footbball   2017-02-10 10:11:05     2
100          ALex       ringball    2017-02-10 10:11:08     2
100         Alex        football    2017-02-10 10:12:10     3
```

Comment: What if there's a row with `10:10:15`, is this part of the 1st group or a new group?

Comment: it should be a new group i guess @dnoeth .. per the explanation..all rows within 8 seconds of each other per user have to be in one group starting at the first timestamp.

Comment: Why did you rollback ObsidianAge's edit? But `10:10:15` is within 8 seconds after `10:10:08`.

Comment: Yes please, it should be new group, basically I'm looking for assigning the  same rownumbers to customers who purchase more than one item with in 8 seconds of time interval..

Comment: Apologies..Unknowingly I had rollback ObsidianAge's edit

Comment: Your point is valid,could you please tell us how do we achieve the group by function for the Time Intervals

Comment: You need a recursive, see http://community.teradata.com/t5/Teradata-Applications/Problem-to-reset-date-column-in-a-scenario/td-p/10859

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it with a recursive cte. Reset the running total of difference from the previous row's timestamp when it gets > 8 to 0 and start a new group.

```
WITH ROWNUMS AS
  (SELECT T.*
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TM) AS RNUM 
         /*Replace DATEDIFF with Teradata specific function*/
         ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,COALESCE(MIN(TM) OVER(PARTITION BY ID
                                                ORDER BY TM ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), TM),TM) AS DIFF
   FROM T --replace this with your tablename and add columns as required
   )
,RECURSIVE CTE(ID,TM,DIFF,SUM_DIFF,RNUM,GRP) AS
  (SELECT ID,
          TM,
          DIFF,
          DIFF,
          RNUM,
          CAST(1 AS int)
   FROM ROWNUMS
   WHERE RNUM=1
     UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ID,
          T.TM,
          T.DIFF,
          CASE WHEN C.SUM_DIFF+T.DIFF > 8 THEN 0 ELSE C.SUM_DIFF+T.DIFF END,
          T.RNUM,
          CAST(CASE WHEN C.SUM_DIFF+T.DIFF > 8 THEN T.RNUM ELSE C.GRP END AS int)
   FROM CTE C
   JOIN ROWNUMS T ON T.RNUM=C.RNUM+1 AND T.ID=C.ID
   )
SELECT ID,
       TM,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY GRP) AS row_num
FROM CTE
```

[**`Demo in SQL Server`**](http://rextester.com/ZRQV24967)

Comment: i don't know if there are other ways to get this..especially if groups have to reset when 8 second interval is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Using Teradata's PERIOD data type and the awesome [td_normalize_overlap_meet](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Period_Functions_and_Operators.080.125.html):

Consider table `test32`:

```
 SELECT * FROM test32

+----+----+------------------------+
| f1 | f2 |           f3           |
+----+----+------------------------+
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:00 PM |
|  1 |  3 | 2017-05-11 03:59:01 PM |
|  1 |  4 | 2017-05-11 03:58:58 PM |
|  1 |  5 | 2017-05-11 03:59:26 PM |
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:28 PM |
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:46 PM |
+----+----+------------------------+
```

The following will group your records:

```
WITH 
normalizedCTE AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLE
            (
                td_normalize_overlap_meet(NEW VARIANT_TYPE(periodCTE.f1), periodCTE.fper)
                RETURNS (f1 integer, fper PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(0)), recordCount integer)
                HASH BY f1
                LOCAL ORDER BY f1, fper
            ) as output(f1, fper, recordcount)
    ),
periodCTE AS 
    (
        SELECT f1, f2, f3, PERIOD(f3, f3 + INTERVAL '9' SECOND) as fper FROM test32
    )


SELECT t2.f1, t2.f2, t2.f3, t1.fper, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.f1 ORDER BY t1.fper) as fgroup
FROM normalizedCTE t1
    INNER JOIN periodCTE t2 ON
        t1.fper P_INTERSECT t2.fper IS NOT NULL
```

Results:

```
+----+----+------------------------+-------------+
| f1 | f2 |           f3           | fgroup      |
+----+----+------------------------+-------------+
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:00 PM |           1 |
|  1 |  3 | 2017-05-11 03:59:01 PM |           1 |
|  1 |  4 | 2017-05-11 03:58:58 PM |           1 |
|  1 |  5 | 2017-05-11 03:59:26 PM |           2 |
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:28 PM |           2 |
|  1 |  2 | 2017-05-11 03:59:46 PM |           3 |
+----+----+------------------------+-------------+
```

A `Period` in Teradata is a special data type that holds a date or datetime range. The first parameter is the start of the range and the second is the ending time (up to, but not including which is why it's "+ 9 seconds"). The result is that we get a 8 second time "Period" where each record might "intersect" with another record.

We then use `td_normalize_overlap_meet` to merge records that intersect, sharing the `f1` field's value as the key. In your case that would be `customerid`. The result is three records for this one customer since we have three groups that "overlap" or "meet" each other's time periods.

We then join the td_normalize_overlap_meet output with the output from when we determined the periods. We use the `P_INTERSECT` function to see which periods from the normalized CTE INTERSECT with the periods from the initial Period CTE. From the result of that `P_INTERSECT` join we grab the values we need from each CTE.

Lastly, `Dense_Rank()` gives us a rank based on the normalized period for each group.

Comment: There are three very different answers here that all solve this very difficult problem. Pick one and run with it. There is no easy answer for a gap and island interval problem like this.

Comment: @JNevill: If you want to cover *within 8 seconds* you should use `PERIOD(f3, f3 + INTERVAL '9' SECOND)`, currently you cover 16 seconds :-)

Comment: @Dnoeth, I was shooting for +/- 8 seconds, but just +8 would probably work too. It's all being normalized out anyway, so I think it's a wash. My net is just cast superfluously wide, I suppose.

Comment: You will combine 10:10:00 and 10:10:15 when you do +/- 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to interpret the problem differently from vkp.  Any row within 8 seconds of another row should be in the same group.  Such values can chain together, so the overall span can be more than 8 seconds.

The advantage of this method is that recursive CTEs are not needed, so it should be faster.  (Of course, this is not an advantage if the OP does not agree with the definition.)

The basic idea is to look at the previous date/time value; if it is more than 8 seconds away, then add a flag.  The cumulative sum of the flag is the row number you are looking for.

```
  select t.*,
         sum(case when prev_dt >= dateandtime - interval '8' second
                  then 0 else 1
             end) over (partition by customerid order by dateandtime
                       ) as row_number
  from (select t.*,
               max(dateandtime) over (partition by customerid order by dateandtime row between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_dt
        from t
       ) t;
```

Comment: @vkp . . . Why don't they just fix that?  There is "lag", it is just spelled differently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hear! hear! A `lag()` and `lead()` would be nice to have in Teradata. `max(<field>) over (... ROWS BETWEEN ...)` is cumbersome and not intuitive at all.

Comment: Are lag and lead part of the ansi standard?  I'm thinking `rows between...` is, but `lag` and `lead` aren't, but I could be completely insane.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Yes they are standard window functions.  And given that Teradata supports the functionality it is rather surprising that they don't just put the functions in.